# How can I used SearchView if I have two modes

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to do a search in title bar 
I have a `ListView` and `GridView` and a method  `switchView()` that switch between these two modes. I added the items by `ArrayList` . I want to search the item in search bar
and I used **this code in MainActivity**

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main2, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.app_bar_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView)item.getActionView();

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                listViewAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                gridViewAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);

                return false;
            }
        });


        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }
```

When I run the program a message come **Unfortunately my app has stopped** . When I removed **the code in the above**  and make it `return false` the app work but of course without search.
**This is logcat debug and error**

```
10-29 14:13:28.681 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'SurfaceFlinger' died
10-29 14:13:28.709 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'simphonebook' died
10-29 14:13:28.709 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'iphonesubinfo' died
10-29 14:13:28.709 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'isms' died
10-29 14:13:28.709 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'phone' died
10-29 14:13:28.709 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'carrier_config' died
10-29 14:13:28.709 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'isub' died
10-29 14:13:28.748 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'telecom' died
10-29 14:13:28.748 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'search' died
10-29 14:13:28.748 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'dropbox' died
10-29 14:13:28.748 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'wallpaper' died
10-29 14:13:28.748 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'input_method' died
10-29 14:13:28.748 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'accessibility' died
10-29 14:13:28.748 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'mount' died
10-29 14:13:28.748 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'uimode' died
10-29 14:13:28.748 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'lock_settings' died
10-29 14:13:28.749 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'deviceidle' died
10-29 14:13:28.749 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'device_policy' died
10-29 14:13:28.749 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'statusbar' died
10-29 14:13:28.749 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'clipboard' died
10-29 14:13:28.749 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'network_management' died
10-29 14:13:28.749 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'textservices' died
10-29 14:13:28.749 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'network_score' died
10-29 14:13:28.749 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'netstats' died
10-29 14:13:28.749 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'netpolicy' died
10-29 14:13:28.749 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'wifip2p' died
10-29 14:13:28.749 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'wifi' died
10-29 14:13:28.749 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'wifiscanner' died
10-29 14:13:28.749 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'rttmanager' died
10-29 14:13:28.749 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'ethernet' died
10-29 14:13:28.750 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'connectivity' died
10-29 14:13:28.750 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'servicediscovery' died
10-29 14:13:28.750 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'updatelock' died
10-29 14:13:28.750 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'notification' died
10-29 14:13:28.750 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'devicestoragemonitor' died
10-29 14:13:28.750 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'location' died
10-29 14:13:28.750 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'country_detector' died
10-29 14:13:28.750 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'imms' died
10-29 14:13:28.750 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'audio' died
10-29 14:13:28.750 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'DockObserver' died
10-29 14:13:28.750 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'midi' died
10-29 14:13:28.750 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'usb' died
10-29 14:13:28.751 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'serial' died
10-29 14:13:28.751 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'user' died
10-29 14:13:28.751 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'procstats' died
10-29 14:13:28.751 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'meminfo' died
10-29 14:13:28.751 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'gfxinfo' died
10-29 14:13:28.751 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'dbinfo' died
10-29 14:13:28.751 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'cpuinfo' died
10-29 14:13:28.751 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'permission' died
10-29 14:13:28.751 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'processinfo' died
10-29 14:13:28.751 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'sensorservice' died
10-29 14:13:28.751 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'jobscheduler' died
10-29 14:13:28.751 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'backup' died
10-29 14:13:28.751 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'appwidget' died
10-29 14:13:28.751 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'voiceinteraction' died
10-29 14:13:28.751 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'diskstats' died
10-29 14:13:28.751 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'samplingprofiler' died
10-29 14:13:28.751 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'commontime_management' died
10-29 14:13:28.752 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'dreams' died
10-29 14:13:28.752 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'assetatlas' died
10-29 14:13:28.752 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'graphicsstats' died
10-29 14:13:28.752 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'print' died
10-29 14:13:28.752 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'restrictions' died
10-29 14:13:28.752 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'battery' died
10-29 14:13:28.752 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'media_session' died
10-29 14:13:28.752 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'usagestats' died
10-29 14:13:28.752 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'webviewupdate' died
10-29 14:13:28.752 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'scheduling_policy' died
10-29 14:13:28.752 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'telephony.registry' died
10-29 14:13:28.752 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'media.camera.proxy' died
10-29 14:13:28.752 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'account' died
10-29 14:13:28.752 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'content' died
10-29 14:13:28.752 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'vibrator' died
10-29 14:13:28.752 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'consumer_ir' died
10-29 14:13:28.752 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'alarm' died
10-29 14:13:28.752 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'window' died
10-29 14:13:28.752 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'input' died
10-29 14:13:28.753 964-1644/? W/AudioFlinger: power manager service died !!!
10-29 14:13:28.755 972-972/? D/fingerprintd: binder died
10-29 14:13:28.755 972-972/? D/FingerprintHal: ----------------> fingerprint_close ----------------->
10-29 14:13:28.758 965-965/? E/installd: eof
10-29 14:13:28.758 965-965/? E/installd: failed to read size
10-29 14:13:28.758 965-965/? I/installd: closing connection
10-29 14:13:28.758 950-950/? I/lowmemorykiller: ActivityManager disconnected
10-29 14:13:28.758 950-950/? I/lowmemorykiller: Closing Activity Manager data connection
10-29 14:13:28.760 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'media_router' died
10-29 14:13:28.760 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'trust' died
10-29 14:13:28.760 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'fingerprint' died
10-29 14:13:28.760 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'batterystats' died
10-29 14:13:28.760 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'appops' died
10-29 14:13:28.760 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'power' died
10-29 14:13:28.760 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'display' died
10-29 14:13:28.760 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'launcherapps' died
10-29 14:13:28.760 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'media_projection' died
10-29 14:13:28.760 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'package' died
10-29 14:13:28.760 951-951/? I/ServiceManager: service 'activity' died
```

**logcat erro**

```
10-29 14:13:28.758 965-965/? E/installd: eof
10-29 14:13:28.758 965-965/? E/installd: failed to read size
```

Comment: add your crash log

Answer (score 0):

It must be the problem with your mode becuase as you said there should be one mode at a time and it will search from that specific selected mode. But in your case, you are searching in both. You are getting both filters and searching. Hope that helps

Comment: it is working with me now thanks but there is no result